# using regular expressions in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I don't understand how I should use regular expressions in `groovy` despite it having several operators to work with it.

```
import java.util.regex.*

def line = "Line with 1 digits"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
Matcher m = p.matcher(line)
if (m.find()) { // true
    println "found digit"
} else {
    println "not found digit"
}

if (line ==~ /\\d+/) { // false
    println "found"
} else {
    println "not found"
}

if (line =~ /\\d+/) { // false
    println "found"
} else {
    println "not found"
}
```

In my example in `java` code it found that there is a digit in the string successfully. However in `groovy` it was not able to do it.

What is wrong?

Comment: `if (line =~ /\d+/)` - use 1 backslash.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh I see. So I had to use double slash if I used double quotes instead of `/`?

Comment: Yes, if you use a regular string literal, you'd need to use a double ``\``. I posted an answer with some reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [slashy string reference](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_slashy_string):

> Slashy strings are particularly useful for defining regular expressions and patterns, as **there is no need to escape backslashes.**

You need to use a single backslash with `\d` in `/\d+/` Groovy slashy strings defining a regex.

```
if (line =~ /\d+/) { // false
    println "found"
} else {
    println "not found"
}
```

The `line =~ /\d+/` checks if a `line` *contains* one or more digits.

The `line2 ==~ /\d+/` checks if the whole string consists of only digits.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Jcu6BG).

Also, see some [more information about using regex in Groovy at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html).

Comment: A short question *(isn't relevant with this answer)*. Do I need to escape dash character (`-`) using backslash ? Actually both of them works for me as well. anyway which one is correct? `/\-/` or `/-/` ? tnx in advance

Comment: `-` is not a special character outside of a character class so it does not have to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find

```
if (line.find(/\d+/)) {
    println "found"
} else {
    println "not found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition if you need a Boolean, like

```
def myBool = line.find(/\d+/)
```

this returns `null`, if it cannot find it - and the number it matches otherwise.

Same with `line =~ /\d+/` that returns a `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

So to get a Boolean directly you can for example extend the *Regex* and use `matches`:

```
def myBool = line..matches(/.*\d+.*/))
```